# Linq to XML issue

Tags: linq-to-xml

Boy am I dense at Linq... Linq to XML in particular.  I am trying to get turn this...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Template>
    <TemplateData>
        <Data>
            <ACTIVE>A</ACTIVE>
            <FIRST_NAME> JASON</FIRST_NAME>
            <LAST_NAME>ABATE</LAST_NAME>
            <DOB>2/11/2013 12:01:36 PM</DOB>
            <PHONE/>
                </Data>
         </TemplateData>
</Template>
```

Into this...

```
IEnumerable<DatModel>
```

Where DatModel is equal to this...

```
public class DatModel{
        public int ACTIVE{ get; set; }
        public int FIRST_NAME{ get; set; }
        public int LAST_NAME{ get; set; }
        public int DOB{ get; set; }
        public string PHONE{ get; set; }
}
```

This is what I am trying to do...

```
    IEnumerable<DatModel> templates = (IEnumerable<DatModel>)
                            from templatesList in xDocument.Descendants("Template")
                            select new TemplateModel{
    Template = (
                                from template in templatesList.Element("TemplateData").Elements("Data")
    select new DataModel{
    ACTIVE = template.Element("ACTIVE").Value,
)}.ToList()
};
```

My list keeps coming up as empty.  I am not sure why that is the case.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: a typo on Elements("ACOData") ? (should be "Data") ? And are you trying to convert "0A" to Int32 ?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo for a different property.  I didn't want to print out my entire object...  Ill fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaning up your code a little to have it compile and adding some ToList(), it seems to work.
( I used anonymous class )

```
private static String s = @"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
    <Template>
    <TemplateData>
    <Data>
        <ACTIVE>A</ACTIVE>
        <FIRST_NAME> JASON</FIRST_NAME>
        <LAST_NAME>ABATE</LAST_NAME>
        <DOB>2/11/2013 12:01:36 PM</DOB>
        <PHONE/>
            </Data>
        </TemplateData>
    </Template>";

[Test]
public void myTest()
{

    XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Parse(s);

    var t = (from templatesList in xDocument.Descendants("Template")
            select new
                {
                    Template = (from template in templatesList.Element("TemplateData").Elements("Data")
                                select new
                                    {
                                        ACTIVE = template.Element("ACTIVE").Value
                                    }).ToList()
                }).ToList();

    Assert.AreEqual("A",t[0].Template[0].ACTIVE);
```

}

Comment: It is actually working... I am just doing something stupid somewhere when trying to match the data types in my model.  Thanks for the sanity check.

Answer (score 0):

You model defined not properly (data types is wrong). Also use proper naming conversation.

Try this:

```
public class DatModel
{
    public string Active { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Dob { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}


string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
                <Template>
                    <TemplateData>
                        <Data>
                            <ACTIVE>A</ACTIVE>
                            <FIRST_NAME> JASON</FIRST_NAME>
                            <LAST_NAME>ABATE</LAST_NAME>
                            <DOB>2/11/2013 12:01:36 PM</DOB>
                            <PHONE/>
                                </Data>
                            </TemplateData>
                </Template>";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
IEnumerable<DatModel> datModels =
    doc.Descendants("Data").Select(d => new DatModel
    {
        Active = (string) d.Element("ACTIVE"),
        FirstName = (string) d.Element("FIRST_NAME"),
        LastName = (string)d.Element("LAST_NAME"),
        Dob = (DateTime) d.Element("DOB"),
        Phone = (string)d.Element("PHONE"),
    });
```